# Cannot install formly "Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, yarnpkg, angular-formly

This question may looks dumb, but like two weeks ago, I had no problems with installing it.
Now it looks like that:
[image: Installing formly]

ng add @ngx-formly/schematics --ui-theme=material

I tried install it after/before material and cdk modules, but the result is the same.
I also tried to install all separate formly modules( on the base of projects that I created previously) and I get this error:

```
The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics. You can try using a different version of the package or contact the package author to add ng-add support.
```

I also tried to delete node modules and yarn.lock and init it again, but still it doesn't works.
And also when I create form it just doesn't show.
I also tried to install it with yarn add ...
or -ui-theme=bootstrap, but the result is the same.
Also tried to ng serve, before installing it(read it somewhere on stack), but it also doesn't work.

I have heard that there are some problems with node v.15.6.0, but I'm not sure if it's that.
Here's also my versions:

[image: Angular cli version]

and yarn version is 1.22.5

Update:
I tried to upgrade all the packages with yarn upgrade --latest, then install formly again.
And after:

```
 ng add @ngx-formly/schematics --ui-theme=material
```

I get that:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/config'
Require stack:
- /home/wiktor/angular-material-template/node_modules/@ngx-formly/schematics/utils/ast.js
- /home/wiktor/angular-material-template/node_modules/@ngx-formly/schematics/src/ng-add/index.js
- /home/wiktor/angular-material-template/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- /home/wiktor/angular-material-template/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- /home/wiktor/angular-material-template/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- /home/wiktor/angular-material-template/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- /home/wiktor/angular-material-template/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
See "/tmp/ng-rRKl9j/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found the solution. I had to downgrade angular schematics to previous version( for safety I downgrade two versions):

```
npm uninstall @schematics/angular
npm install @schematics/angular@9.1.0
```

So formly schematics is not compatible with angular 11 schematics.

Comment: This worked for me with the same issue using Angular 11 and trying to run "ng add ngx-bootstrap"